# Visual Studio 2019 Intellisense replace

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, intellisense

I can't understand why intellisense does't want to replace line after dot with suggestion.

[image]

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>, selected suggestion and I expected the `eoID` to be replaced by `fuID`. But I got `item.fuIDeoID = updItem.eoID;`. To complete suggestion I tried to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd> and result was same. Can someone explain how to get `item.fuID = updItem.eoID;` after complete selecting suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to highlight the part you want replaced.  Currently your cursor is in insert mode (so to speak).  You need to highlight the part you want replaced, bring up intellisense, and select the replacement value.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to select text and brought up intellisense with Ctrl + J, because Ctrl + Space not work for this case, and I got what I need!

Answer (score 1):

To replace press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>